# Allow fullscreen - where is this list stored?

Tags: firefox, youtube, fullscreen

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04, Mozilla Firefox 29.0 for Ubuntu Canonical 1.0.

After installation I've watched some YouTube videos and clicked fullscreen, and the popup 'allow full screen?' appeared. By misclick I've clicked 'Don't allow' and 'never ask again'.

Where is this information stored? How can I reverse it? It's very annoying since I can't view embedded YouTube videos in fullscreen until I repair it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you were using YouTube's HTML 5 player (as the "never ask again" in the popup suggests), the fullscreen setting is managed by Firefox (and therefore has nothing to do with Ubuntu or Gnome).

Go to `about:permissions` (just copy it into your address bar), select `www.youtube.com` from the list and change the setting in the *Fullscreen* box.

Comment: still works, great, thx.

Comment: I just had this in Firefox 40. I had to restart firefox before youtube was listed in about:permissions. Also fullscreen was still listed as always ask. Selecting "block" and then "always ask" again fixed it. (Perhaps a new bug in 40, it was released this week)